# How can I turn off auto language detection in highlight.js and render all blocks?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting, markdown

I use redcarpet2 markdown in my site hosted by Github pages. I switch the syntax highlighter from pygments to highlight.js.

I specified the language for each code block by

````
```r
(some r code)
```
````

So I don't need the auto language detection by highlight.js, actually if I don't specify the language it will always mis-recognize my R code to php or perl code.

The problem is: the HTML tag for `<code>` is somehow mixed.

Without rendering, the markdown correctly translate the code block with `<code class="r language-r" data-lang="r"></code>` which should be rendered as R code. But when I load highlight.js and run `<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>`, the auto detect also works and makes the code tags mixed like `<code class="r language-r hljs php" data-lang="r"></code>` where `php` should be eliminated.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Probably your `highlight.pack.js` does not include R language, you can download it [here](https://highlightjs.org/download) just tick the appropriate checkboxes. When HighlightJS sees unknown class for `code` tag it tries to guess automatically right language.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to disable highlight.js auto language detection with [`hljs.configure({languages:[]})`](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#configure-options). It will still hightlight code blocks with a language explicitly specified.

```html
<script>hljs.configure({languages:[]});hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```